# What is the reason for specifying Django URL-Namespaces in the sites url.py?

Tags: python, django, url, namespaces

I'm starting with Django and what puzzles me is the specification of the URL-namespaces. As far as I understand, you specify them in the site projects urls.py, like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And after that, the namespace can be used in templates of the polls app.

What concerns me is: Why is the namespace not specified in the app, which could be reused and get another namespace in another site and therefore the template does not work anymore. I'm thinking of packages in java or namespaces in C++ which are defined in the library and not in the using app.

So can anybody explain to me, why this was designed like it is?

Thanks
Hannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design gives you more flexibility. You can add two instances of one application in your project with different namespaces (for example two admin panels for different types of users).

Moreover, Django has two types of namespaces for applications in urls. Application namespace is the same as package in java or namespace in C++, it's unique app name, which you can use in templates.

As well Django serve app instance namespace, as you wrote in your example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

In this example admin app is accessible by app namespace 'admin', and polls app is accessible by app instance namespace 'pools', which you define apparently.

You can read more about namespaces in documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

> application namespace
>
> This describes the name of the application that is being deployed.
>   Every instance of a single application will have the same application
>   namespace. For example, Django’s admin application has the somewhat
>   predictable application namespace of 'admin'.
>
> instance namespace
>
> This identifies a specific instance of an application. Instance
>   namespaces should be unique across your entire project. However, an
>   instance namespace can be the same as the application namespace. This
>   is used to specify a default instance of an application. For example,
>   the default Django admin instance has an instance namespace of 'admin'.

Url dispatcher look up by app namespaces firstly, and after that if no matches look up by instance namespaces when trying to reverse urls:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls